# System.Net.Http problem in VS 2017 after upgrade to .NET 4.8

Tags: nuget, .net-4.6.1, .net-4.8

I have a project that was using VS2017 and .NET 4.6.1

I upgraded to .NET 4.8 for no pressing reason expecting it to be a minor upgrade, and everything has broken. The references to System.Net.Http aren't recognised even though the file is actually there.

[image]

I have tried:

- Adding binding redirects
- Updating and reinstalling nuget packages
- Removing the System.Net.Http reference and adding it back in again
- Checking all the hints telling the system where to find the file.
- Everything mentioned as a solution in any other Stack Overflow answers.

What helped a bit was uninstalling the nuget package for System.Net.Http and sticking with the framework version... but then I installed a new nuget package that I needed and that had a dependency on the System.Net.Http package, and therefore nuget reinstalled it, and that broke everything again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that upgrading to VS2019 and MSBuild16 completely fixed the problem.

I would go as far as to say that VS2017 isn't compatible with .NET 4.7.2 or .NET 4.8, and I wish there had been some kind of warning before I upgraded my .NET version.

Comment: (Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 on Win7 SP1) you can add .NET 4.7.2 SDK and the targeting pack by the Visual Studio Installer from the Individual components tab.
For .NET 4.8 you can manual download and install the "developer pack"
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net48-developer-pack